# ActionContext.getContext().getSession() and NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, session, struts2, httpsession

I am developping an application with Struts2, Spring, Spring security and Hibernate.

I need to use session, I try to define my session with this code:

```java
    
Map session =  ActionContext.getContext().getSession();//line 1
session.put("objet",objet);// line2
```

But it returns an `java.lang.NullPointerException` (line1)
Do you have any idea about this problem?

**LoginAction.java**

```
public class LoginAction  extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, Preparable, AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
private UserDetails userDetails;
private User userConnecte;
private Map session;
@Autowired
private UserBO userBO;
// DI via spring
public void setUserBO(UserBO userBO) {
    this.userBO = userBO;
}
/**
 * Getters and setters
 * @return
 */
public User getUserConnecte() {
    return userConnecte;
}

public void setUserConnecte(User userConnecte) {
    this.userConnecte = userConnecte;
}
public User getSession() {
    return session;
}

public void setSession(Map session) {
    this.session = session;
}

public void prepare() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
throws IOException, ServletException {

    
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
            this.userDetails =  (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
        }
        this.userConnecte = this.userBO.retournerUserByEmail(this.userDetails.getUsername());
        this.session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
        session.put("userConnecte", this.userConnecte);
        

}

}
```

Comment: Where do you use this code?

Comment: in my LoginAction class

Comment: Could you post the source code related to your question?

Comment: Done! this is my LoginAction class

Comment: Don't use S2 action as an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use action context when an action was initiated by the struts2 filter. The method
`onAuthenticationSuccess` has nothing with struts2 and action context. Use servlet request object to get session.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one,initialize your Servlet Action Context,

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

           request=(HttpServletRequest)ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
           String userObject=request.getParameter("userConnecte");
            Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
           if (!(auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
                this.userDetails =  (UserDetails) auth.getPrincipal();
           }
           this.userConnecte = this.userBO.retournerUserByEmail(this.userDetails.getUsername());
           this.session= ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
           if(this.userObject!=null){
           session.put("userConnecte", userObject);
           return "login_successful";
           }else{
           logger.info(" userObject is null."+userObject);
           retrun "re_login_page";
            }
 }
```

Comment: There is already a `request` passed to this method as an argument. There is no need to retrieve from action context.